# How to group through a string part?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, aggregate-functions

I've a table which contains logs from a web portal, it contains the url visited, the request duration, the referer...

One of these columns is the *path info* and contains strings like following:

```
/admin/
/export/
/project2/
/project1/news
/project1/users
/user/id/1
/user/id/1/history
/user/id/2
/forum/topic/14/post/456
```

I would like to calculate with sql queries some stats based on this column, so I would like to know **how can I create aggregate based on the first part of the path info**?

It'd let me count number of url starting by `/admin/`, `/export/`, `/project1/`, `/project2/`, `/user/`, `/forum/`, ...

Making it with a programming language would be easy with regex, but I read that similar function does not exists on SQLServer.

Comment: First part of solving the problem, find out how to extract first part of path. The rest is easy.

Answer (score 2):

I would use CHARINDEX() to find the first occurrence of the "/" starting AFTER the leading first character '/', so anything AFTER the second is stripped off.

```
  select
          LEFT( pathInfo, CHARINDEX( '/', pathInfo, 2 )) as RootLevelPath,
          count(*) as Hits
       from
          temp
       group by
          LEFT( pathInfo, CHARINDEX( '/', pathInfo, 2 ))
```

[Working result from SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf7ce/1)

Answer (score 0):

DRapp's is perfect for grouping on the first fragment of the URL.  If you need to group by other levels it might get unwieldy to manage the nested LEFT/CHARINDEX statements.

Here's one way to group by a parameterized level:

```
declare @t table (pathId int identity(1,1) primary key, somePath varchar(100));
insert into @t
    select '/admin/' union all
    select '/export/' union all
    select '/project2/' union all
    select '/project1/news' union all
    select '/project1/users' union all
    select '/user/id/1' union all
    select '/user/id/1/history' union all
    select '/user/id/2' union all
    select '/forum/topic/14/post/456' union all
    select '/forum/topic/14/post/789' union all
    select '/forum/topic/14/post/789'


declare @level int =1;

;with fragments as
(   select  pathId,
            [n] = x.query('.'),
            [Fragment] = x.value('.', 'varchar(100)')
    from    (   select  PathId, 
                        cast('<r>' + replace(stuff(somePath, 1, 1, ''), '/', '</r><r>') + '</r>' as xml)
                            .query('r[position()<=sql:variable("@level")]')
                from @t
            ) d (PathId, X)
)
select  count(*), [path] = max(r.v)
from    fragments f
cross
apply   (   select  '/' + p.n.value('.', 'varchar(100)')
            from    fragments
            cross
            apply   n.nodes('r')p(n)
            where   PathId = f.PathId
            for xml path('')
        ) r(v)
group
by      fragment;
```